# (Visual Basic) How to split a string value into an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, split

I have an array of strings:

`array()`

and

`string = "('one','two','three', ...)"`

The values one two three are examples. The string may have more than three words.

How can I fill the array() with:

```
"one"
"two"
"three"
...
```

Comment: Drop the first three and last three characters, then split at `"','"`.

Comment: This would give me then: one','two','three

Comment: That is why I wrote the "then split at" part

Comment: woops, just noticed the ' ' haha. How can I drop the first and last letters?

Comment: Can there be commas inside the strings?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim s = "('one','two','three', ...)"
Dim tokens = From token In s.Trim("(", ")").Split(","c)
             Select token.Trim("'"c)
Dim array() As String = tokens.ToArray()
```

Remember to add `Imports System.Linq`

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ayy0y1

Note that it's not necessary to use LINQ, i just found it more readable than:

```
Dim array As String() = s.Trim("(", ")").Split(","c)
For i As Int32 = 0 To array.Length - 1
    array(i) = array(i).Trim("'"c)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Though from line Select and onwards it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Alexander: You have added `Imports System.Linq`? Added a demo to my answer

Comment: @Alexander: also provided a LINQ free version

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using .NET 3.5. I just tried the non Linq version, and the strings still have a space and a ' in front of the strings.

Comment: @Alexander: then you use a different char. Just use the correct one in the last `Trim`. As you see also the non-linq version works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eEkZJ3

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Split to break up the starting string into an array populated with the split items.

```
Dim items = "one two three four five"
Dim array = items.Split(" ")
' Outputs array = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ]
```

Comment: That isn't the pattern of string that the question is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is with the use of Regex:

```
Dim str As String = "('one','two','three')"
str = RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "\('|'\)", "")
Dim array() As String = RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(str, "','")
```

If there are spaces to remove then:

```
Dim str As String = "( 'one','two' , 'three ')"
str = RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "\s+|\(\s*'|'\s*\)", "")
Dim array() As String = RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(str, "','")
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the string as you presented it:

```
Dim myString As String = "('one','two','three')"
Debug.WriteLine(myString)
```

Output:

```
('one','two','three')
```

Next get rid of the unwanted characters by replacing them with empty quotes (nothingness).  The Chr(39) function represents the single quote:

```
myString = myString.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(Chr(39), "")
Debug.WriteLine(myString)
```

output:

```
one,two,three
```

Next convert it to an array with the .Split() method:

```
Dim myStringArray() As String = myString.Split(",")
For i As Integer = 0 To myStringArray.Length - 1
    Debug.WriteLine(myStringArray(i))
Next i
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
```

This works without any "Imports" statements